# sed read a file, get a block before specific line

Tags: sed

I am trying to process a file

```
File: /var/log/audit/audit.log:
        /var/paas/sys/log/kubernetes/audit.log
        /var/paas/sys/log/csms-storagemgr/audit.log
File: /var/log/sudo.log: Good
File: /var/log/secure: Good
```

For lines not started with 'File:', I need to combine it with above line

Expected result will be

```
File: /var/log/audit/audit.log /var/paas/sys/log/kubernetes/audit.log /var/paas/sys/log/csms-storagemgr/audit.log
File: /var/log/sudo.log: Good
File: /var/log/secure: Good
```

How to achieve this goal with `sed` or something other tools for it?

I have tried with

```
sed -ne '/File:/{:a;N;/File:/!{ba};s/\n/\t/g;p}' /tmp/test
```

but it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^File:/{:a;N;/\nFile:/!s/\n\s*/ /;ta;P;D}' file
```

Match a line beginning `File:`.

Append the next line.

If the appended line does not begin `File:`, replace the newline and any other following white space by a single space.

If the substitution was successful, loop back and append the next line etc.

Otherwise, print/delete the first line in the pattern space and begin the sed cycle again.

N.B. Trying to read beyond the end of the file with the `N` command, will do what you would expect and print the current line.

Comment: Um, failed. If there are 2 parts in the file need to be combined. It will only combined the first part. For my example, if the first 3 lines was duplicated again, inserted from line 4. It will fail to combine.

Answer (score 2):

With `GNU awk`, assuming amount of spaces do not matter.

```sh
$ awk -v RS='File:' 'NF{$1=$1; print RS, $0}' ip.txt
File: /var/log/audit/audit.log: /var/paas/sys/log/kubernetes/audit.log /var/paas/sys/log/csms-storagemgr/audit.log
File: /var/log/sudo.log: Good
File: /var/log/secure: Good
```

- `RS='File:'` sets `File:` as input record separator
- `NF` so that empty records are not printed
- `$1=$1` rebuild input record based on output field separator, which is space by default
- `print RS, $0` print value of `RS` followed by space and then value of rebuilt input record

Default input field separator is single space character, which will remove leading/trailing space/tab/newline characters and splits a record into fields based on one or more continuous sequence of those three characters. Here's another example:

```sh
$ printf '    a  \t  b      3   '  | awk '{$1=$1; print}'
a b 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. But I have a confusion with `$1=$1`, for example: `echo 'col1,col2' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="|"}{$1=$1;print}'` will work as expected with result `col1|col2`. But `echo 'col1,col2' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="|"}{print}'` will not. But checking input stream as `echo 'col1,col2' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="|"}{print $1}'`, `col1` will be shown as result. That means that input stream has been split as expected.

Comment: @matrixzj yeah, awk will rebuild the input record with new value of OFS only if `NF` or some field value is changed

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe?

```sh
awk '/^File:/ && f { printf "\n" }
  { printf "%s", $0; f=1 }
  END { if (f) printf "\n" }' /tmp/test
```

This omits the newline from the end of each line, then adds it back when it sees the next `File:` line. Notice the `END` block to add back the very final newline after we are done with all the input lines, too.

Demo: https://ideone.com/SCfkx2

If you want to normalize the spaces from beginning of line, try adding `gsub(/^[ \t]+/, " ")` before the `printf "%s", $0`.